# access and use eloquent in created class/different namespace in laravel

Tags: php, sockets, laravel, ratchet

I'm creating a websocket application with Ratchet and Laravel and need to use an Eloquent query within my websocket class, but eloquent isn't available as I use another namespace within the websocket class.

Here's the beginning of the class:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;





class Socket extends Eloquent implements MessageComponentInterface, UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
```

and this is the composer.json with the classmap:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/libraries",
        "vendor/cboden/ratchet/src"   // added this
    ]
```

I've changed the composer.json from the original state to the above, it was like:

```
...
 "psr-0": {                                        //removed this
            "MyApp": "vendor/cboden/ratchet/src",  //removed this 
           }
```

the class Socket resides in app/libraries/Socket.php

Hm, I've pretty much tried everything that comes to my mind, has someone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

The error thrown are:

```
PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'Socket' has no effect in /home/michael/PhpstormProjects/preisopt/app/libraries/Socket-Server.php on line 5

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found in /home/michael/PhpstormProjects/preisopt/app/libraries/Socket.php on line 15
```

This is line 5 of Socket-Server:

```
 use Socket;
```

and this line 15 of Socket:

```
class Chat extends Eloquent implements MessageComponentInterface, UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

I've also tried to write the line like

```
class Chat extends \Eloquent implements MessageComponentInterface, UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

and this throws this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found in /home/michael/PhpstormProjects/preisopt/app/libraries/Socket.php on line 35
```

This is line 35:

```
  $dbtoken = User::where('username', '=', $split[1] )->get('sockettoken');
```

All the classes and models exist and are working when not used in this class.

I've tried so many things that here could be some weird stuff wrong by the time...

Comment: `\Eloquent` is the way to go. Is user inside a namespace? Otherwise just do `\User`.

Comment: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent as Eloquent;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but it sounds like you're running into a misunderstanding about how namespaces work.

This

> PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'Socket' has no effect in /home/michael/PhpstormProjects/preisopt/app/libraries/Socket-Server.php on line 5

Is PHP telling you that the statement

```
use Socket;
```

Doesn't do anything.  The `use` statement lets you tell PHP "Hey, import this class from this other namespace into the current namespace".  When you say `use Socket`, that class `Socket` is already in the current namespace.  If your'e trying to use the global class `\Socket` in another class, you want to say

```
use \Socket;
```

If you're trying to use a class in another namespace whose base name is `Socket`, you want to say

```
use Namespace\Path\To\Socket 
//or
use \Top\Level\Namespace\Path\To\Socket
```

depending on the current namespace of the file.

The errors

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found in /home/michael/PhpstormProjects/preisopt/app/libraries/Socket.php on line 15
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found in /home/michael/PhpstormProjects/preisopt/app/libraries/Socket.php on line 35

Make is sound like you're trying to use the global classes `\Eloquent` and `\User` inside a namespaced file.  You'll either need to add a

```
use \Eloquent;
use \User;
```

at the top of the file, or reference these global classes with the leading backslash in your file whenever you use them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! My question confused me, too BTW :)

Comment: @baao "Your question is a little confusing" is code for "I might be answering the wrong question" :)

Comment: I know, I know. But it ended up as the exact right answer for my problem!